# Accessing Whatsapp functionality without a phone

Tags: android, iphone, whatsapp

I'm looking for a way to access the WhatsApp functionality from code. I've looked it up but it seems like WhatsApp didn't publish any API.

Does anyone know of an alternative way of doing that? Maybe using a 3rd party library?

Comment: I'm guessing you need a PC/web-version or an emulator. Or a computer with the android OS

Comment: And once you get your computer sending 1000 watsapp message, you will breach there T&Cs and acc banned.

Comment: Of course but i don't think there is a PC/web-version and using an emulator is just what i want to avoid

Comment: WhatsApp does not provide any API.

Comment: I've updated my answer: it's now possible with the Yowsup library.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** No, you cannot do that without an emulator. WhatsApp does not have a PC version nor an API. It only runs on mobile devices.

**Longer answer:** Yes, you can do that without an emulator. You just need to reverse-engineer the application and find out how it works internally. Then you can create an application that mimics the behavior of the mobile version of the app but on PC. That requires considerable skill and it's most likely against the terms of use of WhatsApp, so you cannot do that anyway.

**Alternative answer #1:** Just use an emulator. I've read that WhatsApp works fine with [YouWave](http://youwave.com/).

**Alternative answer #2:** Consider whether you need to use WhatsApp at all, or if you could switch to some other app that has a PC support. For example, the [eBuddy XMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ebuddy.android.xms) app seems to do the same thing that WhatsApp does, plus it also seems to have a web interface.

---

**Update on 2017-01-11:** There's now a [Python library called Yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) that does exactly what you want! I came across it while browsing some random Raspberry Pi stuff, there's [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/WhatsApp-on-Raspberry-Pi/?ALLSTEPS) on how to use Yowsup with it.